# Ansible installs php5filter instead of php5

Tags: ansible

I have a strange problem with **[Ansible](http://ansible.cc)** that I use to install / update / manage my webservers.

I have an installation script that is supposed to make sure that I always have the latest PHP5 module in my **Debian 6** / **Apache 2** system:

```
  - name: install apache2 and php5
    action: apt pkg=$item state=latest
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - php5
      - libapache2-mod-php5
      - php5-curl
      [...]
    notify:
      - restart apache
```

It usually works great, but once every few runs I end up with mod-php5-filter in my apache instead of mod-php5 - which is bad for various reasons (mainly for breaking everything).

All I have to do then is run my installation script again - and I'm back to mod-php5

Any ideas? Anything that I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that it's being dragged in as a dependency for php5.

```
apt-cache show php5
Package: php5
Priority: optional
Section: php
Installed-Size: 20
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <pkg-php-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Version: 5.3.3-7+squeeze14
Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.3.3-7+squeeze14) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.3.3-7+squeeze14) | php5-cgi (>= 5.3.3-7+squeeze14), php5-common (>= 5.3.3-7+squeeze14)
```

If it thought libapache2-mod-php5 was unavailable at the time of apt pkg=php5 then it would get the next in the list of dependencies for libapache2-mod-php5filter. Does it happen less if you swap the order of your `with_items:`?